# Why does parted and df show different disk sizes

Tags: partitioning, mount

I know this question has been asked, but the answers usually account for 1-5% differences. My calculated disk space is vastly different using the two command, sda2 should be 20TB but df -h shows only 3.9TB. Thanks for your help.

`$ df -h`

```
FilesystemSize  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sdd1        72G   46G   23G  67% /

udev             32G   12K   32G   1% /dev

tmpfs           6.3G  808K  6.3G   1% /run

none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock

none             32G  216K   32G   1% /run/shm

/dev/sde1       135G  188M  128G   1% /work/data1

/dev/sda2       3.9T  3.0T  758G  80% /work/data
```

`$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT         LABEL

sda              20T

├─sda1            1M

├─sda2 ext2      20T /work/data2

└─sda3 swap      64G

sdd           136.8G

└─sdd1 ext4   136.7G /

sde    ext2   136.8G

└─sde1 ext4   136.7G /work/data1

sr0            1024M
```

`$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 21998.3 GB, 21998285619200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2674472 cylinders, total 42965401600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sda1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
```

`$ sudo parted -ls`

```
Model: DELL PERC H800 (scsi)

Disk /dev/sda: 22.0TB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags

 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                        bios_grub

 2      2097kB  21.9TB  21.9TB  ext2                  msftdata

 3      21.9TB  22.0TB  68.7GB  linux-swap(v1)

Model: SEAGATE ST9146803SS (scsi)

Disk /dev/sdd: 147GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags

 1      1049kB  147GB  147GB  primary  ext4         boot

Model: SEAGATE ST9146803SS (scsi)

Disk /dev/sde: 147GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags

 1      1049kB  147GB  147GB  primary  ext4
```

Comment: short answer : they default to different block size.

Comment: I'm sure you will find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2#File_system_limits) educational.

Answer (score 2):

`df` shows the size of the *filesystems*, `parted` and `lsblk` show the size of *partitions*. Your 20 TB partition `/dev/sda2` contains an **ext2** filesystem. What does `tune2fs -l /dev/sda2` say about it? In particular, what is the block size? Note that if the block size is 1 KiB then the maxium size of an ext2 filesystem is 4 TiB.

Comment: $ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Block count:              1058932736
Reserved block count:     52946636
Free blocks:              251055696
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
I am not sure why it is setup with ext2, should I be thinking about backing up the data and changing to ext4?

Comment: Since the block size is 4 KiB the maximum size of an **ext2** filesystem is 16 TiB. You can use `resize2fs` to enlarge it up to the maximum size, but you won't be able to use the entire partition. If possible, move the data somewhere else and format the partition with a less ancient filesystem.

Comment: So I changed the file structure to ext4
 sudo parted -ls
Model: DELL PERC H800 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 22.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                        bios_grub
 2      2097kB  21.9TB  21.9TB  ext4                  msftdata
 3      21.9TB  22.0TB  68.7GB  linux-swap(v1)

but the size is still 3.9 TB

df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       3.9T  3.0T  766G  80% /work/data2

Should I run resize2fs?

Comment: Yes. Is is better to umount the filesystem first, run `resize2fs` then `fsck -p` (for peace of mind) and re-mount it. You may want to update `/etc/fstab` with the new filesystem type.

Comment: resize2fs /dev/sda2     
resize2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)     
resize2fs: New size too large to be expressed in 32 bits

Comment: To go beyond 16 TiB te file system needs to be created with the 64-bit feature `mkfs -t ext4 -O 64 ...`. `man ext4` says:  "[The feature] **64bit** _Enables  the  file  system  to  be  larger than 2^32 blocks.   This  feature  is  set  automatically,  as needed, but it can be useful to specify this feature explicitly if the  file  system  might  need  to  be resized  larger  than  2^32  blocks,  even if it was smaller than that threshold when it  was  originally created_". And, although the manual page does not say, you need a 64-bit kernel to mount it.